# How to auto resize content with different browser

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I was just wondering how or what i could do to make all my content automatically re-size depending on what browser/ device someone is on. Please Help!

Comment: What you tried so far? What you find ?

Answer (score 0):

You should look at libraries like [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/) and/or [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) which take a lot of the pain out of responsive design.

There are lots of guides online about this:

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Responsive_web_design)
[W3 Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_responsive.asp)

And when all else fails, [Google is your friend](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=responsive+web+design+tutorial).

Answer (score 0):

You could look into vw, vh, vmin, vmax which fits best to your site. These are units like px or % in sizing something but resize. Check this out: https://web-design-weekly.com/2014/11/18/viewport-units-vw-vh-vmin-vmax/.

Answer (score 0):

Use **CSS Responsive** technique.

Responsive means use **the percentage(%)**, instead of pixed values(px).

We can apply different style for different window size with the help of CSS media Query.

**Other way - You can use css framework for responsive,**

[Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/)